# How to fit data with piecewise linear function in matlab with some constraints on slope

Tags: matlab

I am trying to fit a piecewise linear equation for my `(xdata, ydata)` data. I have to challenges, the first one is how to convert the equation in the form of the function handle and the second one is how to put a constraint on the slope, for instance, `a2>a1` and `a2>0` and `a1>0`.

```
xdata = 5:0.2:40;
ydata = max(18,xdata) + 0.5*randn(size(xdata));
a1 = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0); a2 = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
if x < x1;
    f(x) = y0 + a1*(x-x0);
else
    f(x) = y0 + a1*(x1-x0) + a2*(x-x1);
end
FU = matlabFunction(f)
x0 = 5; y0 = 16;
x = lsqcurvefit(FU,[x0,y0],xdata,ydata)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to creating the piece-wise function is to replace the `if` condition by a vectorized `>`. By calling `y = x > 1` on some array `x`, the output `y` will be an array of the same size as `x`, with a logical `True` if the corresponding element in  `x` is larger than 1, and a `False` otherwise. For example

```
>> x = [1, 2, 4; 3, 1, 2];
>> y = x > 2
y =

  2×3 logical array

   0   0   1
   1   0   0
```

You can utilize this to create a piece-wise linear function, as follows:

```
>> fun = @(theta, xdata) theta(1) + ...
                         (xdata<=theta(2)) .* theta(3) .* xdata + ...
                         (xdata>theta(2)) .* (theta(3) * theta(2) + ...
                                              theta(4) .* (xdata-theta(2)))
```

The parameter vector `theta` will be 4-dimensional: the first element is a constant offset from zero, the second element is the corner point, and the third and fourth elements are the two slopes.

By multiplying `theta(3).*xdata` with the result of `xdata<=theta(2)`, you get `theta(3).*xdata` for each point in `xdata` which is smaller than `theta(2)`, and `0` for all others.

Then, calling [`lsqcurvefit`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) is as simple as

```
>> theta = lsqcurvefit(fun, [0; 15; 0; 1], xdata, ydata)

theta =

   18.3793
   17.9639
   -0.0230
    0.9943
```

[image: Resulting Plot]

The [`lsqcurvefit`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) function also allows you to specify a lower bound `lb` and an upper bound `ub` for the variables you want to estimate. For variables where you don't want to specify a bound, you can use e.g. `inf` as bound. To make sure that your `a1` and `a2`, i.e. `theta(3)` and `theta(4)` are positive, we can specify the lower bound to be `[-inf, -inf, 0, 0]`.

However, the `lsqcurvefit` function doesn't allow you to add the constraint `a2 > a1` (or any linear inequality constraints). In the example data, this constraint probably isn't even necessary as this is obvious from the data. Otherwise, a possible solution would be to replace `a2` by `a1 + da`, and use a lower bound of `0` for `da`. This makes sure that `a2 >= a1`.

```
>> fun = @(theta, xdata) theta(1) + ...
                         (xdata<=theta(2)) .* theta(3) .* xdata + ...
                         (xdata>theta(2)) .* (theta(3) * theta(2) + ...
                                             (theta(3)+theta(4)) .* (xdata-theta(2)))
>> theta = lsqcurvefit(fun, [0; 15; 0; 1], xdata, ydata, [-Inf, -Inf, 0, 0], [])

theta =

   18.1162
   18.1159
    0.0000
    0.9944
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer with a thorough explanation!