# Linear piecewise fit (3 lines) is too sensitive to initial knots positions

Tags: linear-regression, curve-fitting, data-fitting, piecewise

I have some set of experimental data (signal vs time):
[image]

I want to fit these curves as linear piecewise functions. I need it, because:

1) I am interested in times of "jumps" (middle part)

2) I want to sort out top-right curve.

To perform a fit I try to use solution, described on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602835/how-to-fit-data-with-piecewise-linear-function-in-matlab-with-some-constraints-o), but this recipe (or at least my implementation) is very sensitive to initial knots positions. My code with results:

```
 %% Generate dummy data
x=linspace(-2,2,100); y=sinh(x)./cosh(x).^2;
% add noise
y=y+(rand(1,numel(y))-0.5)*0.1;
%% Estimate knots
d=(max(x)-min(x));
X0_badEstimation=[min(x)+d/5,  min(x)+4*d/5];
X0_goodEstimation=[min(x)+d/3,  min(x)+2*d/3];
%% Estimate piecewise fit
idx=1:min(10,numel(x));
p1=polyfit(x(idx),y(idx),1);
idx=max(0,round(numel(x)/2-10)):min(round(numel(x)/2+10),numel(x));
p2=polyfit(x(idx),y(idx),1);
idx=max(0,(numel(x)-10)):numel(x);
p3=polyfit(x(idx),y(idx),1);
%% estimate slopes
s1=p1(1); s2=p2(1); s3=p3(1);
%% estimate offsets
o1=p1(2); o2=p2(2); o3=p3(2);
%% model in form
% y=(o1+s1*x)*((x0-x)>=0)+(o2+s2*x)*((x0-x)<0)*((x0+delta)-x>=0)+(o3+s3*x)*(((x0+delta)-x)<0)
model=@(P,x) (P(6)+P(3).*x).*((P(1)-x)>=0)+...
    (P(7)+P(4).*x).*((P(1)-x)<0).*((P(1)+P(2))-x>=0)+...
    (P(8)+P(5).*x).*(((P(1)+P(2))-x)<0);
%% Initial parameters:
x0=X0_goodEstimation(1);
delta=diff(X0_goodEstimation);
P0_goodEstimation=[x0,delta,s1,s2,s3,o1,o2,o3];
x0=X0_badEstimation(1);
delta=diff(X0_badEstimation);
P0_badEstimation=[x0,delta,s1,s2,s3,o1,o2,o3];
%% fit it!
Pfit_goodEstimation = lsqcurvefit(model,P0_goodEstimation,x,y);
Pfit_badEstimation = lsqcurvefit(model,P0_badEstimation,x,y);
%% plot results
hold all
plot(x,y,'LineWidth',3)
plot(x,model(Pfit_badEstimation,x))
plot(x,model(Pfit_goodEstimation,x))
legend({'data','bad knots estimation','good knots estimation'},'FontSize',24)
```

[image]

**Several comments on code:**

1) The function, which i use to generate dummy data: `y=sinh(x)./cosh(x).^2` has no sense for me, I found it empirically, and use just to provide running code.

2) I try different approaches to estimate knots positions better, but on real data I was unsuccessful, so here I use some simple way jus for demonstration.

## Question:

Could You help me with this fitting? Do I have mistake in implementation, or in my case some different method should be used?

Comment: In the graphs with a single transition, the location of the transition center looks like it can be found with "((maxY - minY) / 2) + minY" if that might be of some use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using an continuous empiric fit function?
The super noisy data either does not converge properly, producing an error, or has a rather large fitting errors in one or more parameters. You may additionally check the chi square error of the fit result.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fit_fun( x, a, b, c, d, e ):
    return a + b * x + c * np.tanh( d * ( x - e ) )

# some data
xData= np.linspace( -2, 7 ,37 )
yData = dict()
yData[ 1 ] = np.fromiter( ( np.random.normal(scale = 0.25 ) -10 + 0.3 * x + 3 * np.tanh( 4.5 * ( x - 2.3 ) ) for x in xData ), np.float )
yData[ 2 ] = np.fromiter( ( np.random.normal(scale = 2.50 ) + 3 - 1.0 * x + 0.3 * np.tanh( 4.5 * ( x - 2.3 ) ) for x in xData ), np.float )
yData[ 3 ] = np.fromiter( ( np.random.normal(scale = 0.25 ) -10 - 0.3 * x + 2 * np.tanh( 3.5 * ( x - 2.8 ) )+ 2 * np.tanh( 4.8 * ( x - 1.8 ) ) for x in xData ), np.float )
yData[ 4 ] = np.fromiter( ( np.random.normal(scale = 0.25 ) -10 + 0.3 * x + 3 * np.tanh( -.85 * ( x - 2.3 ) ) for x in xData ), np.float )

# plotting 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = dict()
for i in range( 1, 5 ):
    ax[i] = fig.add_subplot( 2, 2, i)
    ax[i].plot( xData, yData[i] )

# fitting and plotting
sol = dict()
pcov = dict()
for i in range( 1, 5 ):
    aStart = np.mean( yData[i] )
    bStart = 0
    cStart = max( yData[i] ) - min( yData[i] )
    dStart = 1
    eStart = ( max( xData ) + min( xData ) ) / 2.
    try:
        sol[i], pcov[i]  = curve_fit( fit_fun, xData, yData[i] , ( aStart, bStart, cStart, dStart, eStart), maxfev=5000 )
        ax[i].plot( xData, fit_fun( xData, *sol[i] ) )
        print pcov[i].diagonal()
    except RuntimeError:
        print "could not fit data {}".format(i)
plt.show()
```

Giving either:

[image: With fail]

```
>>[8.67452955e-03 1.20595620e-03 9.66526422e-03 3.29572838e-01 3.02484309e-04]
>>could not fit data 2
>>[0.06241828 0.00990755 0.1092549  0.02299717 0.00160222]
>>[0.07924285 0.01274575 0.19154392 0.00806664 0.00194379]
```

or:
 [image]

```
>>[8.29671770e-03 1.15356171e-03 9.10475233e-03 6.58578994e-01 2.20470826e-04]
>>[3.02704593e+02 1.57603966e+01 8.43995977e+02 4.56342636e-01 2.72302001e+00]
>>[0.0467695  0.00741241 0.08193284 0.01793236 0.0012683 ]
>>[0.0475788  0.00819175 0.11240722 0.01152346 0.00221799]
```